# passing lambda to joinToString in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, iterator

I am new to Kotlin and I am struggling to understand following code:

```
println((1..5).joinToString(", ") { (it * 2).toString() }) // 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

From my understanding the above code should have been written like this:

```
println((1..5).map { it * 2 }.joinToString(", ")) // 2, 4, 6, 10
```

To which function are we passing the lambda `{ (it * 2).toString() }` and why do we have `.toString()` there? I didn't find any clue in [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) of `joinToString` either. So, how does this work?

Comment: You're passing the lambda to `joinToString()`. If the last parameter of a function is a function, you can place the lambda outside the parentheses. This is called "trailing lambda" and is mentioned in the documentation. For an explanation of the lambda behavior in this case, look at the documentation for `joinToString`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) has an optional parameter called `transform` of type `((T) -> CharSequence)?`. If a non-null argument is passed for that parameter, `joinToString` will run it on each element of the receiver collection before joining the elements into a string. Let's look at both code snippets you've provided in more detail:

```
println((1..5).joinToString(", ") { (it * 2).toString() })
```

Here, you're calling `joinToString` on a range of `(1..5)`. You're passing a `transform` function, `{ (it * 2).toString() }`, so before joining the elements of the range into a string, `joinToString` will multiply each of them by 2. You'll also need to call `toString()` on the result of the multiplication since the signature of `transform` is `(T) -> CharSequence`.

A piece of general advice: whenever you're confused by Kotlin's terse syntax, reduce the level of terseness until you fully understand the code. In this case, changing the snippet to the following might make it easier to understand:

```
println((1..5).joinToString(", ", transform = { (it * 2).toString() }))
```

The second snippet produces the exact same result:

```
println((1..5).map { it * 2 }.joinToString(", "))
```

You don't need the `transform` function here since the elements are already multiplied by 2 inside `map`.

A note on performance (this is irrelevant here cause the size of the input is too small, but important for large inputs), `map` will have to copy the entire collection, hence the second variant will be slower and less memory efficient. The first variant does not have that problem.